# What happens if I do repo init after repo sync?

Tags: android, github

I have an already synced repo. What happens if I do repo init now and then a repo sync? Will everything be downloaded from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Repo may not allow you to do a repo init in a directory already containing a .repo directory.  Instead, I'd recommend creating a new directory, and then proceeding to call repo init and repo sync.  The newly created directory will then contain everything "from the beginning".